# Propagate user-agent header with IBM API Connect

Tags: rest, api, user-agent, apiconnect

Is there a way to propagate the user-agent header with IBM API Connect?

I am proxying a REST/JSON service, and the user-agent is getting replaced with "IBM-APIConnect/5.0".

I need it for tracking purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using the `set-header` policy in your API assembly, though you need to ensure you're using the `invoke` policy to hit your backend endpoint rather than the `proxy` policy.

Before the the `invoke` policy, add a `set-variable` policy. Configure it as follows:

```
Action: Set
Set: user-agent
Value: $(request.headers.user-agent)
```

This will grab the incoming user agent header value from the request and force it to override the API Connect default.

Comment: I configured the set-variable block before the invoke as you said, but I cannot get it to work. I am using APIConnect 5.x. https://snag.gy/9YiLyd.jpg http://pastebin.com/rtERb1FE

Comment: Are you using API Connect on Bluemix oran appliance on-prem? If the latter, which version?

Comment: On premise appliance, version 5.0.3. With a gatewayscript I can read and change the user agent, but I got "IBM-APIConnect/5.0" as the original user-agent

Comment: @Alessandro did this help solve your problems? If so please mark the question as answered. If not please provide some more detail.