# Adding header to request on IBM API Connect

Tags: apiconnect

When receiving a request on API Connect I want to add a header to the subsequent call that it makes to my backend, I've tried using the `set-variable` policy like so:

```
execute:
  - set-variable:
      title: SetCustomHeader
      actions:
        - value: xxx
          set: X-HEADER-NAME
```

And using the Gateway Script:

```
  - gatewayscript:
      title: gatewayscript
      version: 1.0.0
      source: 'apim.setvariable(''X-HEADER-NAME'', ''xxx'');'
```

I've tried having the action as either `set` or `add`, and I've tried setting the variable name as just the name of the header, and message.headers.X-HEADER-NAME.

According to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610433/propagate-user-agent-header-with-ibm-api-connect), as well as [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/acvfc?topic=gatewayscript-code-examples) either one should work, but when logging the request headers on my backend I still don't see the header.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the apim context variables in order to make api connect understand that you want to set the header value.
so the value will be :

```
- gatewayscript:
      title: gatewayscript
      version: 1.0.0
      source: 'apim.setvariable('message.headers.name' ,'value','set');'
```

Where "name" is the name of the header and "value" is the value of header to be set.

You can find all the api connect context variables here : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/10.0.x?topic=reference-api-connect-context-variables